# Nest is throwing an error for an unrelated module when trying to use Inject a service into AuthGuard

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, dependency-injection, nestjs

#### Current behavior

I have an AuthGuard that basically tracks user Authorizations, I wanted to be able to hit the ProfileService and get some data from it on each request that is using the said AuthGuard

auth.guard.ts

```
import {
  Injectable,
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Inject,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { RequestContextService } from '../middlewares';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { ProfileService } from 'src/individual-profile/services';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly requestContextService?: RequestContextService,
    private jwtService?: JwtService,
    @Inject('ProfileService') private profileService?: ProfileService,
  ) {}
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const request: Request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token = request.headers?.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
    try {
      const user = this.jwtService.verify(token, {
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET.trim(),
        issuer: process.env.JWT_ISSUER.trim(),
      });

      if (!user || !user?._id) return false;
      this.requestContextService.setUserId(user._id);
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

the ProfileService that is being injected is a provider for the IndividualProfile module which I have marked as a Global Module and I've also exported the ProfileService in it

individual-profile.module.ts

```
@Global()
@Module({
  controllers: [
    ProfileController,
  ],
  providers: [
    ProfileRepository,
    ProfileService,
  ],
  exports: [ProfileService],
})
export class IndividualProfileModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): any {
    consumer.apply(RequestContextMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

now the error that I'm seeing is no indication of the above module, whenever I inject the ProfileService into the AuthGuard it throws the following error which has no correlation with any of the two files whatsoever

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the LanguageRepository (wizrxConnection/LanguageModel, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the BadgesModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current BadgesModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within BadgesModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })

    at Injector.resolveSingleParam (/Users/macbookshop/Desktop/MWizer/projects/wizr-x-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:178:19)
    at resolveParam (/Users/macbookshop/Desktop/MWizer/projects/wizr-x-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:116:49)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/Users/macbookshop/Desktop/MWizer/projects/wizr-x-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:131:58)
    at Injector.loadInstance (/Users/macbookshop/Desktop/MWizer/projects/wizr-x-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:57:24)
    at Injector.loadProvider (/Users/macbookshop/Desktop/MWizer/projects/wizr-x-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:84:20)
    at /Users/macbookshop/Desktop/MWizer/projects/wizr-x-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:47:62
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (/Users/macbookshop/Desktop/MWizer/projects/wizr-x-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:47:36)
    at /Users/macbookshop/Desktop/MWizer/projects/wizr-x-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:32:24
```

I've been looking everywhere and couldn't find an answer to resolve my problem.

Comment: Can you also provide code for your BadgesModule and LanguageRepository